# flutter run failed with error "Could not resolve the package 'characters' in 'package:characters/characters.dart'."

Tags: android, flutter

Flutter run command

Output
`Could not resolve the package 'characters' in 'package:characters/characters.dart'.`

flutter doctor

```
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
```

Comment: I just resolved with [this from github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59645#issuecomment-645236663)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the the issue installing https://pub.dev/packages/characters

Comment: Thanks for sharing this workaround, but long-term this shouldn't be necessary. flutter clean seems like a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 19):

I faced this error too while updating Flutter today to Flutter Channel beta, 1.20.0-7.2.pre for an existing project.
As mentioned in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59645#issuecomment-645236663 running: `flutter clean` solved the problem.
This actually deletes the `.dart_tool` plus a few other files.

Answer (score 7):

It could just be an issue with flutter's cache.

Run `flutter clean` to clear your cache.

Comment: this solution,worked for me. upgrade to Channel stable, 1.20.1, on Microsoft Windows

Answer (score 6):

I faced with this Error today (when i updated to **Flutter 1.20.0-7.2.pre • channel beta**) and finaly i solved it with deleting the `.dart_tool` (location: `../yourProject/.dart_tool`) folder in my project and run my project again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to repeat the same solution as it is already been given:
Yes, '**flutter clean**' does the job cleaning the unused files from the previous version.
I though have a habit to run this command periodically and upon each upgrade to keep clearing the cache. And for the past 2 years, I am not facing such issues.

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands and hopefully your problem will be solved:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

or

```
flutter clean
```

then try to run it with

```
flutter run
```

command

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [Flutter Issues on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62674)  run the following commands:

```
flutter pub cache repair
flutter clean
```